# Context-free grammar (CFG)

Tags: computer-science, formal-languages, context-free-grammar

How do I generate a context free grammar for a language
$$\Sigma = \{0, 1\},\ L = \{1^i0^j1^k \mid i, j, k \geq 0\}$$
Thanks already

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  What are your thoughts on the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote our context free grammar by $G=(V, \Sigma, R, S)$ whereby $V=\{S,S_1, S_2, S_3\}$ is our set of variables, $S$ denotes the start variable and $\Sigma=\{0,1\}$ is our set of terminals. Then our rules $R$ are given by
\begin{alignat}{1}S &\to 1S_1\\\
S_1 &\to 1S_1\ |\ S_2\ \\
S_2 &\to 0S_2\ |\ S_3\ \\
S_3 &\to 1S_3\ |\ \epsilon
\end{alignat}

We can generate the following words:

- $101$
- $1\cdots 01$
- $101\cdots$
- $10\cdots 1$
- $10 \cdots 1 \cdots$
- $1 \cdots 0 \cdots 1$
- $1 \cdots 0 \cdots 1 \cdots$

**EDIT**

The above grammar is only valid for the given language for $i,j,k >0$ as @rici correctly pointed out in the comments.

Here is the set of rules for $i,j,k \geq 0$ for the grammar $G=(V, \Sigma, R, S)$ with $V=\{S,S_1,S_2, S_3\}$.

\begin{alignat}{1}S &\to S_1\ |\ S_2\\\
S_1 &\to 0S_1\ |\ S_3\ |\ \epsilon\ \\
S_2 &\to 1S_2\ |\ S_1\ |\ \epsilon \\ 
S_3 &\to 1S_3\ |\ \epsilon
\end{alignat}

This can generate the following words:

- $\epsilon$ (if $i=j=k=0$)
- $1$
- $0$
- $1\cdots$
- $0\cdots$
- $0\cdots 1 \cdots$
- $1\cdots 0 \cdots$
- $1\cdots 0 \cdots 1 \cdots$

Note: with $\cdots$ I mean zero or more repitions.

Comment: Thank you so much. I read my teachers notes for hours but I i couldn't understand
.But now I understand everything :)

Comment: You are very welcome!

Comment: The desired language l also includes sentences starting $0$, which that grammar won't generate.

Comment: I guess that I've missread $\geq$. This should be true for $i,j,k>$. Let me fix it.

Comment: So we can generate the words: ϵ, 1,0,011....  right?

Comment: Let me add the words, that can be generated.